# Add folder and files to VS project using Gulp

Tags: visual-studio, gulp, solution-explorer

Using Visual Studio 2015 Community RC and Gulp 3.8.11. Gulp easily creates tasks to create new folders and files within my Visual Studio project.  However these new folders/files are not automatically added to the project and do not show in the Solution Explorer unless you "Show All Files".  Then, these folders/files must be manually added as necessary.

What changes need to be made to Visual Studio or the gulpfile task in order for new folders and new files to automatically add to the project and show in the Solution Explorer immediately after they are created by Gulp?

Thank you.